# SQL query to find Old clients that have transactions before 2014 but nothing afterwards?

Tags: sql

Self-taught beginner here.
I want to sort out (old) clients that have last transactions in 2014 but nothing else till date.

I tried this:

```
select distinct transact_clntab.chn, transact_clntab.TRADE_DATE, transact_clntab.acct_code from  transact_clntab
WHERE Trade_date not between '2019-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
and TRADE_DATE not between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'
and TRADE_DATE not between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
and TRADE_DATE not between '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
and TRADE_DATE not between '2015-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
and not exists
(SELECT chn, TRADE_DATE, acct_code FROM transact_clntab 
WHERE Trade_date between '2008-01-01' and '2019-12-31'
and TRADE_DATE between '2009-01-01' and '2018-12-31'
and TRADE_DATE between '2010-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
and TRADE_DATE between '2011-01-01' and '2016-12-31'
and TRADE_DATE between '2012-01-01' and '2015-12-31'
and TRADE_DATE between '2013-01-01' and '2017-12-31'
and TRADE_DATE between '2014-01-01' and '2016-12-31')
```

but get no result

THEN
I tried sorting with excel but even more difficult

```
SELECT chn, TRANTYPE, ACCT_CODE, TRADE_DATE FROM transact_clntab 
where TRADE_DATE < '2016-01-01'
order by TRADE_DATE
```

I expect the output to be

```
chn      Transactiontype Account code   Trade date
7683592  SALES           BABA-2688  2008-06-02 00:00:00.000
58987897 PURCHASE        FASH-1492  2008-06-02 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: which data type is the column TRADE_DATE ??

Comment: Why would your desired results have trade dates *after* your cutoff?  That doesn't make sense.  You should also tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want clients whose last trade is in 2014, then use aggregation:

```
SELECT t.acct_code
FROM transact_clntab t
GROUP BY t.acct_code
HAVING MAX(t.trade_date) < '2015-01-01' AND
       MAX(t.trade_date) >= '2014-01-01';
```

If you want information about the last transaction for such accounts, use window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.acct_code ORDER BY t.trade_date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM transact_clntab t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1 AND
      t.trade_date < '2015-01-01' AND
      t.trade_date >= '2014-01-01';
```

Comment: What I want is to FInd clients that started since 2008 and stopped trading in 2014 but hasn't done any transaction(s) from 2014 till date

Answer (score 1):

Try grouping your data over the client id (I'm thinking it is chn) and fetch maximum date and put a condition that date is less than 2015.

```
SELECT transact_clntab.chn, MAX(transact_clntab.TRADE_DATE) last_transaction, transact_clntab.acct_code
FROM transact_clntab
GROUP BY transact_clntab.chn,transact_clntab.acct_code
HAVING last_transaction < '2015-01-01';
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're close. But you're not correlating by the customer, that's why the subquery to `NOT EXISTS` always finds some rows I guess. Your multiple `BETWEEN`s can also be simplified and are probably better replaced by a check of an right open interval.

Assuming `acct_code` identifies the customer, you can try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       tc1.chn,
       tc1.trade_date,
       tc1.acct_code
       FROM transact_clntab tc1
       WHERE tc1.trade_date >= '2014-01-01'
             AND tc1.trade_date < '2015-01-01'
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM transact_clntab tc2
                                    WHERE tc2.acct_code = tc1.acct_code
                                          AND tc2.trade_date >= '2015-01-01');
```

Comment: When i run all i get this:Invalid column name 'transact_clntab'

Comment: @SamuelOlufowote: I forgot to change the aliases. Should be correct with the edit.

Comment: when i run partial : SELECT *
                                    FROM transact_clntab tc2
                                    WHERE tc2.transact_clntab.acct_code = tc1.transact_clntab.acct_code
                                          AND tc2.trade_date >= '2015-01-01' I get The multi-part identifier "tc1.transact_clntab.acct_code" could not be bound.

Comment: @SamuelOlufowote: Just missed another bit. Edited again.

Comment: @SamuelOlufowote: Can you setup a fiddle, so I can test it?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT
       chn,
       TRADE_DATE,
       acct_code
       FROM transact_clntab
       WHERE trade_date >= '2014-01-01'
             AND trade_date < '2015-01-01'
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT chn, TRADE_DATE, ACCT_CODE
                                    FROM transact_clntab
                                    WHERE trade_date >= '2015-01-01');         this one returns no result but i know it is close to what i am looking for

Comment: @SamuelOlufowote: I can just repeat "you're not correlating by the customer".

Comment: How do I set up a fiddle?

Comment: @SamuelOlufowote: Go [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/) and create the table and insert some sample data.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f2c7a16d07a8e891b50d53346a6b956a